# Getting unbound variable error in shell script

Tags: shell

I'm trying to add set -eu option in my script but it's throwing an error "**Unbound variable error"**

```
ssh -q $username@$server << EOF                            
set -eu    
echo "proceeding diagnostics"    
cd $CT_PATH    
bundle exec cap -q -S instance=$instance demo deploy:all;    
echo "completed process"
EOF
```

I would need to add -eu option on the script because -u option can catch non-existent variables.

Appreciate for you quick help on this

Comment: where are you setting values for `CT_PATH` and `instance`? If you're expecting they will be inherited from the environment on $server, then you need to use `<<'EOF'`, and that's assuming those vars as set with `export` in some basic `.rc` file that is sourced by `ssh` . Good luck.

Comment: I'm calling CT_PATH from a separate script and instance name is passing from the input parameters

Comment: Since the only variables in your script are `CT_PATH` and `instance`, and it is unlikely that *bundle* will raise this error message, my guess is that one of these variables are not defined. I suggest that you output their values right before the `set -eu`, for instance like this: `echo ${CT_PATH:-undefined} , ${instance:-undefined}`.

Comment: "Calling from a separate script". Do you mean `source mySepScript` (or `. mySepScript`), because you must "source" a script for its vars to be visible inside a parent script. If you don't know what I mean search here for `[bash] source`. Good luck.

Comment: There was no issue with bundle but the problem is that we are unable to add set -eu option in the script.

i'm calling the script source myscript.sh in the script. still i'm facing unbound variable. 

Can someone please help me out on this?

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this, too. You need to initialize all variables before `set -eu`

My issue was this:

```
...
set -eu

for filename in folder/*.txt; do
    ... stuff ...
done
```

This threw the `unbound variable` issue. However, if I defined `filename` above `set -eu` to an empty string, the issue disappeared.

For your case, it seems like you need to initialize `CT_PATH` or `instance` before `set -eu`